# Python Json manipulation

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to manipulate JSON file data.

What my JSON file looks like:

```json
[
    {
        "sku": "2",
        "view_code": "english",
        "short_description": "xy",
        "product_type": "simple",
        "attribute_set_code": "4"
    },
    {
        "sku": "1",
        "view_code": "english",
        "short_description": "xy",
        "product_type": "simple",
        "attribute_set_code": "4"
    }
]
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```json
[{
  "product": {
        "sku": "2",
        "view_code": "english",
        "short_description": "xy",
        "product_type": "simple",
        "attribute_set_code": "4"
  },

  "product": {
        "sku": "2",
        "view_code": "english",
        "short_description": "xy",
        "product_type": "simple",
        "attribute_set_code": "4"
  }
}]
```

I tried to turn it into a string and loop through it, then making a JSON again, which gave me this result:

[image]

Comment: Your desired result is impossible, because it shows a dictionary with two identical "product" keys.  Dicts can't have duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tmp=[
    {
        "sku": "2",
        "view_code": "english",
        "short_description": "xy",
        "product_type": "simple",
        "attribute_set_code": "4"
    },
    {
        "sku": "1",
        "view_code": "english",
        "short_description": "xy",
        "product_type": "simple",
        "attribute_set_code": "4"
    }
]
```

Load as dictionary in python, then modify it and re store it to json.

```
new_dict = {}
c = 0
for i in tmp:
    c+=1
    new_dict['product'+str(c)] = i
```

Output:

```
{
'product1': {'sku': '2',
  'view_code': 'english',
  'short_description': 'xy',
  'product_type': 'simple',
  'attribute_set_code': '4'},

 'product2': {'sku': '1',
  'view_code': 'english',
  'short_description': 'xy',
  'product_type': 'simple',
  'attribute_set_code': '4'}
}
```

One important note. You can't name different keys in a dictionary with the same name. You must use different names. In this case just the name followed by a number. In the other case you will have just a single key.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks for the note, actually didn't know that the key can't be the same. I need to post that data to a webshop using rest api. Maybe I can find a workaroung for that, bc "product" must always be "product" in order to post.

Comment: @wayx so you can't use a dictionary. If the answer was useful upvote it and mark as correct please.